# What is this houseplant with thin palmate leaves?

Tags: identification, houseplants

What plant is this, and how should I care for it.

I got it in India, just bought it because it looked cute to me, and now I don't know it's name or how to care for it.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have the Kochia Scoparia. It is a hardy, drought-tolerant grass that is said to be toxic and invasive. So please keep it in pots, don't plant it in the ground, unless you have the space. It requires bright sunlight and moderate watering.

Comment: Excellent!  This particular plant needs a pot twice its size!  Tell us a bit more about this plant Nikhil!  What about it is toxic, to what biological form (like us humans, cats, dogs)?  Where it is listed on the 'invasive weed list'...within India? Thank you so very much for answering.  Not all of us get to live in India...or for that matter outside of the U.S.  Not anymore anyway.  Thank you so very much!

Comment: You are most welcome, @stormy yesterday! KS turns a flaming red color in the autumn. Which is why it is also known as Burning Bush. When it dries up, it turns into tumbleweed. In India, we have plants that are ten times more invasive! It is invasive in the US, for sure. It is toxic in that it can cause kidney or liver failure in animals that eat too much of it. I guess that would be predominately herbivorous animals. A simple way of controlling it is by removing the seed heads. 

Here's the Wikipedia link: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassia_scoparia

Comment: Burning Bush here is Euonymus alata.  Brilliant fall foliage.  Most animals that have grown up or are indigenous will know better or maybe....I am a nut watching what may be growing in my horses pasture.

Comment: That's funny. I really thought KS is the original Burning Bush. It will be no surprise if more than one plant turns into a Burning Bush in the autumn or so. For instance, the Canadian maple is a brilliant orange at times, is it not? Not related to this, but I have also seen pics on the net of a purple cactus - the Santa Rita opuntia.
You have HORSES??!! You don't say ... that's just awesome! I've deeply loved them ever since I used to go to school in a horse cart - some 40 years ago! Wow, that's fanta-fabulous! Awesomer!